# Updating FB SDK, getting dependency errors after adding compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'

Tags: android, facebook

Got an email from FB about "v2.5 Upgrade Reminder". Which is going to be deprecated. So, was updating FB SDK to the latest version for which I added gradle dependency in build.gradle (module: app). But after adding it getting alot following dependency errors.

```
 Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2
 Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2
 Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2
 Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2
 Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add specific version of fb library ie. `com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.28.0`

In 4.29.0 facebook used new version of support libraries which was failing with my app. I've needed to update whole app with newest support libraries before updating facebook sdk.